# HTML img: Applying a style

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

Good Afternoon folks,

I am trying to set a style to an img tag. It is working on IE but not working on Chrome.

I am using ASP 3.0 and checking if a variable(qtde_niveis) to change the style of the img

The code is bellow:

```
< img id="test" <% If qtde_niveis > 1 Then %> style="display:''" <%Else %> style="display:none" <%End If%> align="middle" />
```

When I inspect the element in chrome, it keeps showing the img (even when qtde_niveis is 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed value of property `display` here:

```
 <% If qtde_niveis > 1 Then %> style="display:''"
```

Comment: but if i set the display:'' it won't set the display(that is what i need, dont set the display or set as '' if qtde_niveis > 1)

Comment: try to set 'display:block;'

Comment: thanks for you attention. The problem was that there were two styles beeing applyed to the img tag!